# Multiple inheritance with Django

Tags: python, django, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm using Django for a project, and I want to use a couple of apps that extend the admin by subclassing the admin class.

How can I have them both sublass the admin class?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from testing.models import *
from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin
from moderation.admin import ModerationAdmin

class ItemAdmin(VersionAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

Comment: You can't subclass a module. Subclassing is... erm... for classes. Is `class ItemAdmin(VersionAdmin, ModerationAdmin)` what you want? (I doubt it.) If so, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both VersionAdmin and ModerationAdmin appear to use the "cooperative super" feature of Python. So I'd try to just use multiple inheritance:

```
class ItemAdmin(VersionAdmin, ModerationAdmin):
    pass
```

If this fails, you can see whether it works better with the reverse order. If this still fails, you need to study the specific issue, and find out why the cooperative super doesn't work.